# Optimizing Spritesheets in HTML with EaselJS

Tags: html, optimization, easeljs

I'm an iPhone dev and I've been using Spritesheets there for a while.  In iOS, spritesheet image dimensions should be optimized into "Powers of two" (eg 1024x2048) because they allocate memory in those blocks, and other image resolutions would be less optimized.

My question -- is this logic applicable across all platforms?  I'm now using spritesheets in HTML5 with EaselJS and I want to know whether it's better to use "Power of Two" size constraints, or just use any size.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using powers of two does carry into the EaselJS/CreateJS world.  In fact, the recommendation is baked right into the EaselJS source code for [SpriteSheetBuilder](http://www.createjs.com/Docs/EaselJS/SpriteSheetBuilder.js.html) - where both `maxWidth` and `maxHeight` have the comment:

> It is recommended to use a power of 2 for this value (ex. 1024, 2048,
>   4096).

This is also advice given from [Atari Arcade](http://www.atari.com/arcade) which [used CreateJS](http://www.atari.com/arcade/developers/building-atari-createjs).  The [Building HTML5 Games for the Atari Arcade](http://www.atari.com/arcade/developers/building-html5-games-atari-arcade) dev guide has the suggestion:

> Create spritesheets and textures that have dimensions that are a power
>   of two.